# Your Main Activity class com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity is not a subclass FlutterFragmentActivity

Tags: android, flutter, exception, just-audio, flutter-stripe

I'm trying to create music app uses just_audio & just_audio_background plugins, App is working fine but I'm trying to integrate Stripe from flutter_stripe plugin. I get an exception when click on checkout button. its look like class `com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity` from just_audio_background conflicting with flutter_stripe plugin

**Exception**
Your Main Activity class com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity is not a subclass FlutterFragmentActivity.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.spotify
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.spotify"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
   
   <application
        android:label="spotify"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            
        </activity>

      
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    <service android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService"
        android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
        android:exported="true" tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <!-- ADD THIS "RECEIVER" element -->
    <receiver android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver"
        android:exported="true" tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>     
    </application>
</manifest>
```

`

I tried custom activity defining directly into menifest but its not work. please help me I'm newbie

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try `AudioServiceFragmentActivity` instead of `AudioServiceActivity`. More information about the different ways to define an audio service activity can be found in the [audio_service documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service#android-setup).

Comment: ThankYou @rayan now its working. appreciate your help